# how to kill running subprocess while another subprocess is completed (in multiprocessing)

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I came across a problem with multiprocessing:

```python
class PythonHelper(object):
    @staticmethod
    def run_in_parallel(*functions):
        processes=list()
        for function in functions:
            process=Process(target=function)
            process.start()
            processes.append(process)
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
```

The above stathic method is used by me to run several functions simultaneously (combining them in one process). Everything was okay until I came across the need to force the process terminating while one of 'subprocess' is terminated.

For example:

```python
from PythonHelper import PythonHelper as ph
from Recorder import Recorder

class Logger(object):

    def run_recorder_proc(self):
        rec=Recorder()
        rec.record_video()

    def run_printer_proc(self):
    #hypothetical function: execution takes a long time
        for i in range(9000000):
            print("number: {}".format(i))

    def run_logger(self):
        ph.run_in_parallel(self.run_printer_proc,self.run_recorder_proc)
```

**self.run_printer_proc** and **self.run_recorder_proc** are my subprocesses. How to 'kill' remaining subprocess while one of them was completed?

---

Edit:
Full source code:

```python
class PythonHelper(object):
    @staticmethod
    #with your fix
    def run_in_parallel(*functions):
        processes={}
        for function in functions:
            process=Process(target=function)
            process.start()
            processes[process.pid]=process
        # wait for any process to complete
        pid, status = os.waitpid(-1, 0)
        # one process terminated
        # join it
        processes[pid].join()
        del processes[pid]
        # terminate the rest
        for process in processes.values():
            process.terminate()
        for process in processes.values():
            process.join()


class Logger(object):
    def run_numbers_1(self):
        for i in range(900000):
            print("number: {}".format(i))
    def run_numbers_2(self):
        for i in range(100000):
            print("number: {}".format(i))
    def run_logger(self):
        ph.run_in_parallel(self.run_numbers_1,self.run_numbers_2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    logger=Logger()
    logger.run_logger()
```

Based on the above example I would like to force termination of **run_numbers_1** while **run_numbers_2** is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may achieve that by changing `run_in_parallel()` slightly:

```
def run_in_parallel(*functions):
    processes={}
    for function in functions:
        process=Process(target=function)
        process.start()
        processes[process.pid]=process
    # wait for any process to complete
    pid, status = os.waitpid(-1, 0) 
    # one process terminated
    # join it
    processes[pid].join()
    del processes[pid]
    # terminate the rest
    for process in processes.itervalues():
        process.terminate()
    for process in processes.itervalues():
        process.join()
```

**[Update]**
Based on your complete code here is a working example. Instead of race-prone `os.waitpid()` it uses `Event` object, which other processes set when completed:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, event, *args, **kwargs):
        self.event = event
        Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        Process.run(self)
        self.event.set()

class PythonHelper(object):
    @staticmethod
    #with your fix
    def run_in_parallel(*functions):
        event = Event()
        processes=[]
        for function in functions:
            process=MyProcess(event, target=function)
            process.start()
            processes.append(process)
        # wait for any process to complete
        event.wait()
        # one process completed
        # terminate all child processes
        for process in processes:
            process.terminate()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()


class Logger(object):
    def run_numbers_1(self):
        for i in range(90000):
            print("1 number: {}".format(i))
    def run_numbers_2(self):
        for i in range(10000):
            print("2 number: {}".format(i))
    def run_logger(self):
        PythonHelper.run_in_parallel(self.run_numbers_1,self.run_numbers_2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    logger=Logger()
    logger.run_logger()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not want to work. What is initial value of pid? What is the status? It is not used

Comment: It must be that the child processes have terminated before it calls `waitpid`. Can you post the complete script to test it?

Comment: I've posted full source code. I suppose the trouble may be in waitpid. I guess you're happy Linux user :) Unfortunately I'm currently working on Win and this could be a problem.

Comment: I've changed source (too many libs to paste), but the most important source defs are originally. run_numbers_1 and run_numbers_2 are examples of defs that finished in different moments.

Comment: Running the above code caused an error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python32\lib\pickle.py", line 679, in save_global klass = getattr(mod, name) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'MyProcess'`

Comment: I see you are running it on Windose which lacks `fork()`, so that the child process can't get access to the function scope defined class. I updated the code, but I don't have Windows at the moment to try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and patience :) The last solution works exactly like I wanted.